# Operator overloading use * and *= as dot or cross product

Tags: c++, vector

I'm creating a vector class for basic vector operations and trying to decide which one [dot product or cross-product] is the best to overload the `*` and `*=` operator with and would like other people's thoughts.

So far I have the `+`, `+=`, `-`, and `-=` implemented as such.

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator+(const Vector<T>& rhs) {
    Vector<T> result(*this);
    result += rhs;
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator+=(const Vector<T>& rhs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        this->vector[i] += rhs[i];

    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator-(const Vector<T>& rhs) {
    Vector<T> result(*this);
    result -= rhs;
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator-=(const Vector<T>& rhs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->size; i++)
        this->vector[i] -= rhs[i];

    return *this;
}
```

To continue the trend of returning a `Vector<T>` should the cross-product be used for the `*` and `*=` operator overload or return a `T&` from using the dot-product.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered [std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) ?

Comment: This question is off topic because it is entirely opinion based.

Comment: Because of the ambiguity, I would say *neither*. Use something like a `cross` method and a `dot` method to distinguish them. Not everything has to be an operator.

Comment: @quantdev I have and also `std::vector`, but after considering what I will be doing with the class later, a `Vector` class what what I decided is best. Thanks for the thought though!

Comment: Well, as long as we're talking about silly overloading ideas.... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3babaf324d7c7d30

Comment: @MooingDuck, `mathvector::dot` should return a scalar. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you're wondering which operation `*` should mean is a strong hint not to use it.  In fact, `*` and `*=` could also mean component-wise multiplication. Avoiding the confusion is the best option here, so just use the names `dot` and `cross` for the operations, and forget about the `*` operator.

Comment: You can overload `*` for scalar multiplication; that one's naturally and canonically defined.

Comment: I'd overload operator* for dot since sqrt(dot(v, v)) == abs(v). This is consistent with float or double sqrt(f\*f) == abs(f). We give the L2 norm, abs(v), special consideration by calling it THE norm and we use that slur "normalize" to mean v/abs(v) so I'd say we're definitely thinking of v\*v as abs(v)^2.

Comment: @SamuelDanielson Yes, if I saw `v *v` in the source, I would assume that `operator *` was overloaded as the dot product. However, in general, for `u * v`, that may not be clear. Also, as another answer points out, `operator *=` *cannot* be implemented as the dot product, while it can be implemented as the cross product. Neither the dot product nor the cross product satisfy all the basic intuitions people have about scalar multiplication, which is why I advise against using an operator here. A named method is always more readable, unless an operator has some unambiguous and obvious semantics.

Answer (score 1):

**If in doubt, abstain.**

That's the most important advice for [operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706).

Just remember to apply it to each combination of possible input-types separately, so scalar-multiply is ok, dot- and cross-product, because both plausible, shall not be contemplated.

BTW: There's no way to make `*=` mean dot-product, the result is not of the same type as either argument.

Aside: Your `Vector` might be easily confused with standard container `vector`. You might want to address that.

Answer (score -1):

While it would be better to use `dot` and `cross` functions, if you're insistent on making use of the `*` operator, you should use a dot product. Cross products are only valid for vectors in R3, so dot would probably be more useful.

Comment: Cross product is special, yes. The real question is between dot and dyadic product since the dot product in matrix terms is a row vector times a column vector and a dyadic product is a column vector times a row vector.